# combine multiple records into one cell in sql db2

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table with two columns
id and comments:

```
    id comment
    1   test1
    1   test2
    1   test3
    2   test4
    3   test5
```

How can we achieve the below using sql db2 query:
id comment

```
    1   test1,test2,test3
    2   test4
    3   test5
```

Please help.

Comment: Sybase was a company, not a database.  What Sybase database are you referring to (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? other?).  The commands can differ between products, so it's important to specify this in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**LISTAGG**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0058709.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0/2-10-3-1-7):

```
SELECT id, LISTAGG(comment, ',') as comments 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY id
```

Or you could try:

```
SELECT id,
SUBSTR(XMLSERIALIZE(XMLAGG(XMLTEXT(CONCAT(', ', comment))) as VARCHAR(1024)), 3)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id
```

Or try:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(comment SEPARATOR ", ") as comments 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY id
```

Or:

```
SELECT CAT.id,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + SUB.comment AS [text()]
              FROM MyTable SUB
              WHERE SUB.id = CAT.id
              FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 1, '' ) AS Comments
FROM MyTable CAT
```

Comment: sorry.. my apologies.. the Database is sybase. Sorry, new to this team

Comment: **@Alpesh003**, I am not sure what the backend database is.  So, I added some different options.  let me know if any of them work.

Comment: Hey @Linger. Many thanks for your replies. The backend DB is sybase. I tried with the three options but its giving issues.

Comment: How about the last query?